Does a +1 sword count as a magical attack vs Heavy Armor Master feat?
In a combat encounter last weekend, one of my players said their Heavy Armor Master feat should have reduced the damage of a sword swing. When I told them it was from a +1 sword, they said that could just be a masterwork weapon, and not actually magical. It gave me pause and since the module didn't specifically say it was a magical weapon, I granted the damage resistance of the feat like they requested.
But it makes me wonder - Does a +1 sword count as a magical attack vs Heavy Armor Master feat?

Yes it does
D&D 2014 does not have masterwork weapons as a concept. That is an idea from 3rd edition. The term masterwork appears neither the PHB nor in the DMG for 5e, and there is also no other rules mechanic that gives mundane weapons an inherent +1 to hit or damage.
Any weapon +1, including a sword +1, is a magic item in 5e. This is on page 213, DMG, in the magic item section:

WEAPON, +l, +2 , OR + 3
Weapon (any), uncommon (+1), rare (+2), or very rare (+3)


It may be worth noting—though perhaps not, considering this question’s closure—that 3e concepts of “masterwork” and “+1” are very distinct. A masterwork weapon would never be called “+1” in 3e, because it isn’t, it doesn’t receive the same +1 bonus that a +1 weapon does (it gets a +1 on attack, but not on damage), and it isn’t a magical weapon, which is just as crucial in 3e as it is in 5e. (On the other hand, a +1 weapon is a masterwork weapon in 3e, since a weapon is required to be masterwork if it is to receive any magic. Upgrading from masterwork to +1 is the mandatory first step.)
